# web3.eth.defaultAccount not working

Tags: web3js

I would like to set a default account for my web3 operations with web3js but it does not work.

I'm using `web3@1.0.0-beta.29` and here is my code.

```
  const Web3 = require('web3')
  const Token = require('./Token.json')

  const web3 = new Web3(new Web3.providers.HttpProvider())//provider.web3
  web3.eth.defaultAccount = '0x4615ff6690a3bb23bd85051c5c69abba4092bbb4'
  const tkn = new web3.eth.Contract(Token.abi, '0xba9d4199fab4f26efe3551d490e3821486f135ba')

  tkn.methods.transfer('0x4615ff6690a3bb23bd85051c5c69abba4092bbb4', 1e9)
    .send()
    .then(console.log)
    .catch(console.log)
```

the output of this is

```
    Error: No "from" address specified in neither the given options, nor the default options.
```

the [documentation](http://web3js.readthedocs.io/en/1.0/web3-eth.html?#defaultaccount) says that this should not happen

Comment: If you want to send any tras it should be signed with your private key/password. I couldn't see in your code.

Answer (score 1):

I ran into the same problem. I had to explicitly specify the address on the `send` function call, like this:

```
tkn.methods.transfer('0x4615ff6690a3bb23bd85051c5c69abba4092bbb4', 1e9)
    .send({ from: web3.eth.defaultAccount })
```

Comment: the point is to set a defaultAccount and not have to specify the from in every send

Comment: Default account is already set, its just a general value that you can use.

Answer (score 0):

When creating the contract instance , you can set the "from" field in the options. Then all your transactions will default to that address.
You could give the from address as the default Account.

Comment: according to the documentation, the default account should be used for that.

Comment: Please add the link to the documentation that mention that.

Comment: @btc4cash - The docs appear inconsistent. [defaultAccount](https://web3js.readthedocs.io/en/v1.2.6/web3-eth.html#defaultaccount) says it should be used if from is missing. However, [send](https://web3js.readthedocs.io/en/v1.2.6/web3-eth-contract.html#methods-mymethod-send) does not list from as optional.

Answer (score 0):

Your correct, but if you want to send any transaction to eth network. That should be signed with your account/unlocked your account.

//unlock your account before call transfer                    web3.personal.unlockAccount(web3.eth.accounts[1],'abc123');

Or use private key to send information.

Comment: the goal is to have Web3 fill out the FROM automatically. The error has nothing to do with signing